# Generalise output function for standard library containers

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I played with templates. Using them it's possible to abstract from the type of container, for example below vector can be any POD type.

```
template<class T>
void show(vector<T> &a) {
typename vector<T>::iterator end = a.end(), start = a.begin();
  for(start; start!= end; start++) {
      cout<<*start<<" ";
   }
 }
```

I use it so: 
`vector<int> vect_storage; 
       show(vect_storage);`

I wonder is it possible to create such show method which would be capable to show not only vector but map, list, dequeue from STL library  as well?

Comment: I too [was wondering that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking a container as a parameter, take a pair of iterators:

```
template <typename Iter>
void show(Iter first, Iter last) {
  while (first != last) {
    cout << *first++;
  }
}

vector<int> v;
show(v.begin(), v.end());
deque<int> d;
show(d.begin(), d.end());
int arr[10];
show(begin(arr), end(arr));
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: well, of course you first need a suitable `operator<<` overload capable of printing one element, before you can print a containerful of them.

Comment: Maybe I want to much.Actually I didn't pass iterators because I was going to be able to call over containers general methods like  vector::insert or map::insert. With iterators I can't add a new element to the end of array. Or, e.g. I can't call  vector::clear() method. But it's fine for outputting (moreover my question was changed already)

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename Cont> void show(Cont c) {
    copy(cbegin(c), cend(c), ostream_iterator<decltype(*cbegin(c))>(cout, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is already very close. Just remove the vector specification as such & it will work.

```
template<typename T> void show(T& a)
{
    auto end = a.end();
    auto start = a.begin();
    for(start; start != end; start++)
    {
        cout << *start << " ";
    }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    vector<int> a(2,100);
    show(a);
    list<double> b(100, 3.14);
    show(b);
    return 0;
}
```